# ruby regex hangs

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote a ruby script to process a large amount of documents and use the following URI to extract URIs from a document's string representation:

```
#Taken from: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
URI_REGEX = /
(                           # Capture 1: entire matched URL
  (?:
    [a-z][\w-]+:                # URL protocol and colon
    (?:
      \/{1,3}                        # 1-3 slashes
      |                             #   or
      [a-z0-9%]                     # Single letter or digit or '%'
    )
    |                           #   or
    www\d{0,3}[.]               # "www.", "www1.", "www2." … "www999."
    |                           #   or
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?:                           # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+                      # Run of non-space, non-()&lt;&gt;
    |                               #   or
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
  )+
  (?:                           # End with:
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
    |                                   #   or
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]        # not a space or one of these punct chars
  )
)/xi
```

It works pretty well for 99.9 percent of all documents but always hangs up my script when it encounters the following token in of the documents: `token = "synsem:local:cat:(subcat:SubMot,adjuncts:Adjs,subj:Subj),"`

I am using the standard ruby regexp oeprator: `token =~ URI_REGEX` and I don't get any exception or error message.

First I tried to solve the problem encapsulating the regex evaluation into a `Timeout::timeout`block, but this degrades performance to much.

Any other ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why reinvent [the wheel](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M009389)?

```
require 'uri'
uri_list = URI.extract("Text containing URIs.")
```

Comment: See, that's exactly what I mean. +1 for using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). I just loaded your regex and your test string into RegexBuddy, and it gave up after 1.000.000 iterations of the regex engine (and from the looks of it, it would have gone on for many millions more had it not aborted).

The problem arises because some parts of your text can be matched by different parts of your regex (which is horribly complicated and painful to read); it seems that the "One or more:" part of your regex and the "End with:" part struggle over the match (when it's not working), trying out millions of permutations that all fail.

It's difficult to suggest a solution without knowing what the rules for matching a URI are (which I don't). All this balancing of parentheses suggests to me that regexes may not be the right tool for the job. Maybe you could break down the problem. First use a simple regex to find everything that looks remotely like a URI, then validate that in a second step (isn't there a URI parser for Ruby of some sort?).

Another thing you might be able to do is to prevent the regex engine from backtracking by using [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). If you can change some `(?:...)` groups into `(?>...)` groups, that would allow the regex to fail faster by disallowing backtracking into those groups. However, that might change the match and make it fail on occasions where backtracking is necessary to achieve a match at all - so that's not always an option.

Answer (score 0):

`URI.extract("Text containing URIs.")` is the best solution if you only need the URIs.

I finally used `pat = URI::Parser.new.make_regexp('http')`to get the built-in URI parsing regexp and use it in `match = str.match(pat, start_pos)` to iteratively parse the input text URI by URI. I am doing this because I also need the URI positions in the text and the returned `match` object gives me this information `match.begin(0)`.